# Slider with separate background slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an effect for a website which features a large content slider near the top of the page.  Namely, I want to position a larger image behind the `<div>` containing the slider so that it shows outwards from the left, right and bottom, but stays behind other content. (Take a look at the slider on the frontpage of AutoDesk's website for a similar example)  I'm currently using the Foundation 4 framework, and Unslider.js .

Think of this structure:

```
<ul class="slider-background">
    <li class="slider-bckgrnd"><img src="./bg.png"/></li>
    ...
    <li class="slider-bckgrnd"><img src="./bg.png"/></li>
<ul>

<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li class="slide"><img /></li>
        ...
        <li class="slide"><img /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The biggest problem I'm having is figuring out how to get the background image to display **behind** everything else.

I've tried the z-index, but that doesn't work for elements further down the page.  Is the solution an extra wrapper `<div>` around the whole thing?

EDIT:  I want a separate background for each individual slide, and the slides are of varying heights.  I'm handling the positioning via jQuery / javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was much easier than expected.  I simply had to assign `position: relative;` to the `.row`'s from Foundation to allow them to obey `z-index` rules.